# Save contact to app database CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android

In this code I keep getting an error, I know its how I'm saving the contact to the database. because if I take out the cdata/cdata2 and just put a string it works fine. Any help will be appreciated.

How do I convert this to accept the string from the contact?

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case 1:
        //Save current contact to stash database
        Cursor phones2 = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null, null);
        String cdata = phones2.getString(phones2.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String cdata2 = phones2.getString(phones2.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues(2);         
        values.put(DatabaseHelper.NAME, cdata);
        values.put(DatabaseHelper.cALUE, cdata2);  
        db.getWritableDatabase().insert("constants", DatabaseHelper.NAME, values);
        constantsCursor.requery();            
       //Refresh contact list
        Intent refresh = new Intent(this, MainTab.class);
        startActivity(refresh);
        this.finish();

      return(true);
      case 2:
          //uncoded option
          Toast.makeText(this, "here is the info", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

ERROR:
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to call Cursor.moveToFirst(), without this call the cursor will not be ready to be read from.

Try like this

```
//Save current contact to stash database
    Cursor phones2 = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null, null);
  if (phone2.moveToFirst()) {
    String cdata = phones2.getString(phone ......
```

Comment: Yes but that just makes the "CDATA" string pull only the first position of the cursor. I need it to match the list position.

Comment: if you want to match the list position with cursor you can call phones2.moveToPosition(int)